# If I use Executors.newFixedThreadPool, can the executor call an active threads run method while the thread is waiting on a network operation?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

If I use Executors.newFixedThreadPool, can the executor call an active thread's Run method while the thread is waiting on a network operation?

**Sample Code:**

```
public class RequestProcessor implements Runnable{
    private String parsedData,data1,data2;
    
    public void init(DataObject data){
        //add DataObject to queue
    }
    
    private void parseData(){ //THIS SHOULD BE CALLED ONLY BY RUN METHOD
        
        this.parsedData = //take DataObject from queue, parse it and assign 
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.parseData();
        processParsedData(); //TAKES AROUND 200 MILLISECONDS TO COMPLETE USUALLY - WAITS FOR a N/W OPERATION        
    }   
}
```

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int thread_pool_size=10;

        RequestProcessor[] processorPool = new RequestProcessor[thread_pool_size];
        ExecutorService taskPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(thread_pool_size);
        
        for (i = 0; i < thread_pool_size; i++) {
            processorPool[i] = new RequestProcessor();
        }
        
        i=0;

        while (true) {
            if (i >= thread_pool_size) {
                i = 0;
            }

            this.getData(data); //blocks until data is available

            processorPool[i].init(data);
            taskPool.execute((Runnable) processorPool[i]);

            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

If the application gets lots of request, the while loop above gets very active. The executorservice is supposed to create new threads - that is call Run method of a thread from pool whenever a new request comes.

Is it possible that while a thread is waiting on the n/w operation (200 ms), the executorservice can invoke the same thread's Run() method (mistaking it to be free or inactive) thus changing the data of the thread before it completes processing?

Comment: Currently `init()` could be called in the loop at same time as `run / parseData` which is handling a previous value from `getData` call. It's impossible to tell what is going on without seeing how you've implemented `init()` and `parseData()`.

Comment: Init - adds 'data' to a blockingqueue. parseData takes that data from queue and processParsedData  sends that data  to a network service and waits for the response for around 100-200 ms . The idea is when the thread's Run method is called, it shoud take 'data' from queue and parse it. Question is what are all the scenarios when that run method will be called by the executor? I assumed it would happen only when thread is free. But, can it happen when thread is waiting for network response?